# how to assign values to variables left to right using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using EF with MVC and below is a snippet of my code.
 I would like `st.Settings` to take the value of `c.SettingsID == usersID` if `cca` is null

```
var st = context.tblSystem.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SettingsID == usersID);
var cca = context.tblOrganisation.FirstOrDefault(c => c.departmentID == usersID);
if (cca == null)
    st.SettingsID= c.usersID ;
```

Comment: Add this else part - `if (cca == null) { st.SettingsID= c.usersID ; } else { st.SettingsID = userID; }`. I dont see what is the complexity involved in here.

Answer (score 1):

I think is what you are missing is to save the changes after making them, 
at the end of your code add `context.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this will be your code

```
    var st = context.tblSystem.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SettingsID == usersID);
    var cca = context.tblOrganisation.FirstOrDefault(c => c.departmentID == usersID);
    if (cca == null)
          {
            st.SettingsID= c.usersID ; 
            st.Settings = c.usersID == userID
           }
```

But if you mean that your code is not working, I think is what you are missing is to save the changes after making them, 
at the end of your code add `context.SaveChanges()`

Comment: Thank you very much context saveChanges was causing the issue